# Location Details on my Xamarin App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, location

i want to show full details of a place in my app.
i want to show the following items.
1. languages spoken,
2. common phrases
3 cuture
4. currency
5. time zone
6. local tourist attractions etc

How can I do that on Xamarin. From where i can retrieve these details

Answer (score 2):

You can try Google Places Api. You can get details on latitude and longitude base. It might give the info you need.

Comment: i wont get all the details i want from google places API